# How are curling percentage determined by each shot?

Tags: statistics, curling

This is the [scoreboard for the gold medal final for 2017 Tim Hortons Brier](http://www.curling.ca/scoreboard/#!/competitions/2254/games/a670d15d-f60f-a08a-2da0-a6689d398b92).

It is possible to see the percentage (PCT) for each curler for this match.
This percentage coming from every single shot, but

How is it possible to determine this percentage in an objective way?

Comment: Please do not use codeblock for emphasis. It interferes with screenreaders and is difficult to read for some people.

Answer (score 2):

The stones are given points (normally between 0 and 4) depending on how close to the task (as the judges see it) the stone is. This often does not include secondary tasks that the team my set up for a stone, if it is not perfect. So while in theory a game should have the same score independent on who runs the scoring, there are quite a few "grey areas" (eg how good is a guard, should it have 2 of 3 points).

There is also a system of bonus points, but I don't know exactly how these are calculated.

Divide the total points with 4 times the number of stones, and you have a percentage.